# Using the APU for heating on the ground with engines shut down

Tags: aircraft-systems

I would like to refer one technical question to you that I couldn’t able to explain myself. It is from the FCOM Supplementary Procedures Chapter of a Boeing 737 Classic. This question concerns the use of APU as a heat air source on the ground with engines shut down. The supplementary procedure explains that under extremely cold weather conditions both packs may be used for more rapid heating.

It directs to open the Isolation Valve Switch which is reasonable. However it also says that during right pack operation only, under cold conditions, if the left PACK TRIP OFF light illuminates, position the recirculation fan OFF until the cabin temperature stabilizes.

Here, I don’t understand do they mean that left pack is INOP? I am confused because this procedure explains that both packs may be used!? And the other thing, why should I position the left recirculation fan to of if the LEFT TRIP OFF light illuminates under these conditions. As far as I know the recirculation fan reduces the air conditioning pack load, or am I missing something.

Comment: Something is off there - you won't get a Pack Trip on the left pack if it's already turned off. Reread the section and confirm that you aren't mixing up left/right or pack trip vs bleed trip someplace. Also, a pack trip happens when the pack is working hard to cool, not heat, the air. When heating a cold aircraft, a duct overtemp is the most likely light you'll get.